# Azure Automation PowerShell Script runs commands twice

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I have a Azure Automation PowerShell script the gets scheduled to run every night. For some reason every once and while the workflow will run and then just start running all the commands from the beginning again in the same instance of the running workflow. I am not looping the whole workflow or anything so i do not know how or why this is happening. Any thoughts?

Here is the code:

```
workflow Start-SQLDatabaseBackup
{
        param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $credName = 'automation',

        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $SubscriptionName,

        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $SQLServerName,

        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $DatabaseName,

        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $StorageAccountName,

        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $ContainerName ='backup',

        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string] $time


    ) 
    inlinescript {

        Write-Output ("Starting Database Backup for " +  $Using:DatabaseName)

        $Credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name $Using:credName
        if($Credential) 
        {            
            Write-Output ("Found Automation Credential Asset named " + $Using:credName)
        }
        else
        {
             throw ("Could not find an Automation Credential Asset named" +  $Using:credName + ". Make sure you have created one in this Automation Account." )
        }       

       $SQLCredential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name '****' 

        if($SQLCredential) 
        {            
            Write-Output ("Found SQL Credential Asset named " +  $Using:SQLcredName)
        }
        else
        {
             throw ("Could not find an SQL Credential Asset named " +  $Using:SQLcredName + ". Make sure you have created one in this Automation Account.")
        } 


        Add-AzureAccount -Credential $Credential > $null
        Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $Using:SubscriptionName

        if (!(Test-AzureName -Storage $Using:StorageAccountName))
        {  
            Write-Output ("Creating Storage Account "  + $Using:StorageAccountName)
            New-AzureStorageAccount -StorageAccountName $Using:StorageAccountName -Location $Using:Location 
        }

        Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $Using:SubscriptionName -CurrentStorageAccountName $Using:StorageAccountName

        $SqlContext = New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext -ServerName $Using:SQLServerName -Credential $SQLCredential
        if($SqlContext) 
        {            
            Write-Output ("Created SQL Context for " +  $Using:SQLServerName)
        }
        else
        {
             throw ("Could not Create SQL Context for " + $Using:SQLServerName + ". Make sure SQL Credential Asset named" +  $Using:SQLcredName + " has access to the server" )
        }
        $time = $Using:time
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($time) )
        {
            $start = [System.DateTime]::UtcNow
            $time = $start.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hh-mm-ss-tt") 
        }

        $fileName = ( "{2}/{0}_{1}.bacpac" -f $Using:DatabaseName, $time, $time )


        $Container = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name $Using:ContainerName
        if($Container) 
        {            
            Write-Output ("Retrieved Azure Storage Container - " + $Using:ContainerName)
        }
        else
        {
             throw ("Could not Retrieve Azure Storage Container " +  $Using:ContainerName + ". Make sure the Storage Container exists. " )
        }
        Write-Output ("Starting Copy of " +  $Using:DatabaseName)

        $dbCopyName = ($Using:DatabaseName +"_copy")
        $dbCopy = Start-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy -ServerName $Using:SQLServerName -DatabaseName $Using:DatabaseName -PartnerDatabase $dbCopyName
        $doLoop = 1

        while ($doLoop -eq 1)
        {
            $copyStatus = Get-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy -ServerName $Using:SQLServerName -DatabaseCopy $dbCopy -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            if ($copyStatus -ne $null)
            {
                Write-Output $copyStatus.PercentComplete
                Start-Sleep -s 10            
            }
            else
            {
                $doLoop=0
                Start-Sleep -s 10
            }
        }
        Get-AzureSqlDatabase -ConnectionContext $SqlContext -DatabaseName $dbCopyName

        Write-Output ("Starting Export of " +  $dbCopyName )
        $exportRequest = Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport -SqlConnectionContext $SqlContext -StorageContainer $Container -DatabaseName $dbCopyName -BlobName $fileName
        if ($exportRequest)
        {
            $doLoop = 1
            while ($doLoop -eq 1)
            {
                $exportStatus = Get-AzureSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -Request $exportRequest
                if ($exportStatus.Status -eq "Completed")
                {
                    $doLoop = 0               
                }
                elseif ($exportStatus.Status -eq "Failed")
                {
                    $doLoop = 0 
                    throw ("Exporting database " + $dbCopyName + " failed")
                }
                else
                {
                    Write-Output $exportStatus.Status
                    Start-Sleep -s 10
                }
            }

          Write-Output ("Backup " + $fileName + " Created" )
        }
        else
        {
            throw ("Error Creating Export Request for " + $dbCopyName)
        }
      Write-Output ("Deleting " +  $dbCopyName) 
      Remove-AzureSqlDatabase -ConnectionContext $SqlContext -DatabaseName $dbCopyName -Force

    }
}
```

And here is the output. You can see it starts running the commands from the top of the script again after it finished.

```
 Starting Database Backup for *****
    Found Automation Credential Asset named ****
    Found SQL Credential Asset named 
    Created SQL Context for *****
    Retrieved Azure Storage Container - backup
    Starting Copy of ******
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    100
    Starting Export of ******
    Pending
    Running, Progress = 0%
    **Starting Database Backup for ********  < -- Starts running from the top of script again?
    Found Automation Credential Asset named ****
    Found SQL Credential Asset named 
    Created SQL Context for *******
    Retrieved Azure Storage Container - backup
    Starting Copy of *****
    Starting Export of *****
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running into Azure Automation's ["fair share"](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-runbook-execution/#fair-share) limit, where we unload any job that takes more than 3 hours (to make sure other jobs have a chance to run), and then resume the job from its last checkpoint (if there are no checkpoints in the runbook, like in your case, the job will resume from the beginning).

If you want to ensure certain parts of your runbook are not rerun in the case where the Azure Automation fair share limit is reached, make sure your runbook jobs will complete in under three hours, or add checkpoints (via Checkpoint-Workflow) after parts of the runbook that should not be repeated.

Comment: Hmm...Interesting. I think that might be it. Thanks!

Comment: My runbook starts the rerun after 1:05 minutes. That's not fair!