# Azure Runbook restart scripts without error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I have a `Powershell` script which is working perfectly on a local machine. My script is uploading data to a `blob storage` by selecting from an `Azure sql data warehouse`.

When i upload small tables it works fine. However when I try to upload from a big table it restarts my script without any error.

So I am really clueless on why it starts all over again at some point. For me it could smell like some kinda timeout or something. But I cannot find our where. And there is no error-messages.

```
try
{

   #Remove files to cleanup
   $deletefilelist = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container "XXXXXXX" -Context $context

    foreach ($listfiles in $deletefilelist)  
    {
      $removefile = $listfiles.Name
      if ($removefile -ne $null)
      {
        Write-Output "removeing file $removefile"

        Remove-AzStorageBlob -Blob $removefile -Container "XXXXXXX"-Context $context -Force
      }
    }

  #SQL connection settings
  $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
  $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = False; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"
  $SqlConnection.Open()

  #MetaData CMDs
  $SqlCmdMeta = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
  $SqlAdapterMeta = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter

  #Datasets
  $DataSetMeta = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
  $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

  #Getting metadata from table in Az DWH
  $SqlMetaQuery = "Select FullTableName,TableName,Category,MapSourceSystem,SQLStatement from XXXXXXX"

  $SqlCmdMeta.Connection = $SqlConnection
  $SqlCmdMeta.CommandTimeout = 0
  $SqlCmdMeta.CommandText = $SqlMetaQuery

  $SqlAdapterMeta.SelectCommand = $SqlCmdMeta

  $SqlAdapterMeta.Fill($DataSetMeta)
  $metadataoutput = $DataSetMeta.Tables[0]  

  Write-Output "Preparing settings and upload to blob.."
  #Build the blob file name and sql
  $Todaydate = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmmss"
  foreach ($row in $metadataoutput) {
    $category = $row.Category
    $mapsourcesystem = $row.MapSourceSystem

    $csvfileName = $category + "_" + $row.TableName + "_$mapsourcesystem" + "_$Todaydate"


    #Check if it is a fact table. If it is a fact table then the SQLStatement should have an attached mapsourcesystem to the where clause
    $SqlFilename = $row.TableName
    if ($category -eq "Fact") {
      $SqlQuery = $row.SQLStatement + " '$mapsourcesystem'"
    }
    else {
      $SqlQuery = $row.SQLStatement 
    }
    $SqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0      
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery


    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    Write-Output "Rows Detected"

    #Check if table is empty
    if ($DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count -eq 0) {
      Write-Output $csvfileName" does not contain any rows in SQL Database and therefore is a CSV file not created"
    }

    else {
      Write-Host "Building and uploading blob file to storage.."
      #Create the blob file and upload it to blob storage
      $file = New-TemporaryFile
      $DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv -Path $file -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation 
      Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File $file -Container "XXXXXXX" -Context $context -ClientTimeoutPerRequest -1 -ServerTimeoutPerRequest -1 -Force -blob $csvfileName".csv"

      Write-Output $ErrorActionPreference
      Write-Output $csvfileName " Has been uploaded to the Blob storage with success!"

      Write-Output "Deleting $csvfileName in temporary enviorment"
      #Remove-Item -Path $Env:Temp -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
      $DataSet.Reset()
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's related to [fair share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-execution#fair-share) limit. For more information, refer Joe's answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817701/azure-automation-powershell-script-runs-commands-twice) Stack Overflow thread.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah! Okay! Then IMO it would be related to some transient issue / error like sandbox crash & a new one was spun up, etc. I suggest to design script to be idempotent & robust in order to handle such possibility. For more information w.r.t related suggestion, refer [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-execution#runbook-behavior). If this still doesn't help you then I recommend to go for Azure support where support engineer would be able to check Kusto logs based on respective runbook execution job id and would be able to diagnose issue in a better way.

Comment: Thanks :) I will try to look into it. I also found out that because i am loading data into a DataTable I use the in-memory capacity of a runbook. And i think the limit is around 400 mb. I solved the issue by using a azure function instead which had more capacity.

Comment: Glad to know that the issue is resolved by using Azure Function. :) Thanks for sharing the information regarding using in-memory capacity of runbook.